# calculating how many lines of code in ipython notebook

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

just for curiosity sake - is there a way to find how many lines of code you've written in your ipython notebook? I have multiple lines per box, so I can't just count the number of boxes I have...

Comment: There's nothing out of the box to count lines, but it would be easy to write a Python script or a JS function to iterate through the cells and add up the line count.

Comment: how would you do that?

Comment: For Python, you can use the `IPython.nbformat` package. For JS, open up your browser's javascript console when you've got a notebook open, and poke around `IPython.notebook`.